# How Matrix A is called $A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Something like evolve matrices, there is a definition in wikipedia but I can not find it. (Not idempotent) 
There are 3 type of matrices that are called this way.
Thanks

Comment: Equal to identity matrix? I know about [nilpotent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NilpotentMatrix.html), [idempotent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IdempotentMatrix.html) and periodic matrices.

Comment: Not idempotent matrices

Comment: [Involutory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix) matrix.

Comment: That's it @m0nhawk!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [involutory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix) matrix.

Seeing the $\mathbf{A}^2 = \mathbf{I}$, recalling the definition of inverse matrix: $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{-1} = \mathbf{I}$.

Then, an [involutory](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvolutoryMatrix.html) matrix is a matrix that is its own inverse.